# Tridion Schema Lock down to specific groups

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to lockdown few schemas to specific groups. e.g; Schema "SuccessStroy" will not be aviable to "GroupB". I applied the permissions to the folder where the schemas exist. The folder permissions are in such a way that "No Read" access to the "GroupB". I have the hide organizational items enabled set to true.

From GUI, when GroupB users login and try to create the component they see the schema "SuccessStory" in the drop down, but when they select they see a message "you do not have access ..". So the permissions for sure are correct, but However when the drop down displays for some reason it is not respecting the permissions and still giving the option to users to select the restricted schema.

Anybody experienced this behavior.?

Environment: Tridion 2011 GA + HR 1, Windows 2008 R2 Sp1, .net 4.

Note: The behavior is not just limited to schemas, I have noticed the same for Page Templates and Component Templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a defect on 2011 GA, I am not sure if there was a hotfix, but it was definitely fixed on SP1.

I couldn't find a hotfix that specifically addresses this issue, might be worth checking with Customer Support if you need a hotfix before upgrading.

Comment: Thanks Nuno. I will check with Customer Support to see if there is any hotfix available for Tridion GA + HR # 1. Upgrade to SP1 is on our future plan, but not immediately.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION/FIX:** Tridion Customer Support provided a hotifx for 2011 GA + HR # 1 and the issue has been resolved now. If any one experiencing the same problem, please contact customer support.

Ideally, it would be great if you can migrate to Tridion 2011 SP1 version where the issue is already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

We also faced such problem regarding the page templates. And that Time hotfix was not avaialble. And on suggestion Of Nuno Linhares we contacted the customer support. Not hotfix for the page templates is available.

Comment: Alok, Are you saying the hotfix now available for page templates ? If yes, may be you edit your answer to clearly say that hotfix is available.